# Rail dirty and date changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a column in orders called closed_date which is a DateTime field.

Using Dirty.  trying to do `if self.closed_date_changed?` but it's not working. Do I have to do something special for tracking changes with Date Time fields?

---

EDIT
Using Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2p136

Code in orders controller

```
def update
 @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
    @order.close_order
  end
 end
end
```

In Model

```
include ActiveModel::Dirty

def close_order
  if self.closed?
    if self.closed_date_changed?
      self.items.each do |item|
        item.update_attribute(:created_at, self.closed_date)
      end
    end
  else
    self.update_attributes(:closed_date => Time.now, :closed => true)
    self.items.each do |item|
       item.update_attribute(:created_at => Time.now)
          item.schedule_any_tasks
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Can you put some code example when you see this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
def save_changes
  if closed_date_changed?
    # do something like save the modified data to a table
  else
    # do anything else
  end
end
```

And the most important, don't forget to call this method on a before_save(update) callback.

Because the changes only remains while the actual record isn't saved.

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried and gave me error - undefined method `changed?' for 2011-04-04 00:00:00 UTC:Time

Comment: Kieber means: if closed_date_changed?

Why this works: update_attributes should save the model already, so by the time you're checking for dirty in your original example code the object has already been saved and is, in fact, clean.

But using this in a before_save filter will trigger everything before the save and your changed? will work

Comment: Yep, worked.  Can someone my understand why it works as before filter and not in my model?

Answer (score 0):

```
def start_date_changed?
  return true  if self.start_date != self.start_date_was 
  return false
end
```

I have use **was** which checks for the value change..

Thanx